# eclipse mars how to set colors of specific UI items

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 for Java on Windows 10, there are several items I can't figure out how to change the color of, and web searches are difficult since I don't know the names of the items, and the few I do know have changed over time, are for other windows versions, or older Eclipse versions. Many others address the issue only for Unix hosts. I would appreciate pointers to where to change these colors for Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 on Windows 10:

**screen captures**

[image]

In the first capture: the preferences window font color, black in the screen capture. Also the blue "links" to other information.

In the second capture: the blue link color in the "fixes" popup window. Many pages claim this is related to the system link colors, but changing the link & visited link colors in Internet Options had no effect. I cannot find this blue color in any of the color settings I could find in Eclipse itself. I restarted after changing it in windows, with no effect.

In the third capture, the suggested/help text within input box, which is so dark it cannot be read.

In the fourth capture, the color of the virtual memory bar and text.

In the fifth capture, the background and foreground colors of the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Are you trying to set them by creating/modifying a CSS theme or some other way?

Comment: By any means necessary, but I have been trying to use the preferences window under General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts, General->Editors->Structured Text Editors, General->Editors->Text Editors, and Java->Editor